# C# Clock In / Clock Hour - Total Time Worked

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan, buttonclick

**PROBLEM:** Create a program consisting of a Clock In Button, Clock Out Button, and Label to hold the total time worked.

This code seems like it should be simple but I know I'm missing something. I can't get the DateTime clockIn from the inButton click to use with TimeSpan in the outButton click. I'm pretty new to C# so any criticism is welcome. Thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TimeClock
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void inButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           DateTime clockIn = DateTime.Now;
        }

        public void outButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime clockOut = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan timeWorked = clockOut - clockIn;

            string timeWorkedReport = $"Time worked = {timeWorked.Hours} hours, {timeWorked.Minutes} minutes";

            timeLabel.Text = timeWorkedReport;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Local variable vs Class data member.. ehh

Comment: One can only assume that `totalTimeWorked` should be simply `clockout-clockin` but is it? Does the assignment say anything about that?

Comment: Oh and for your next question: I guess this gives you a compilation error. If you have one or in other cases maybe an exception, always include those in your question.

Comment: Note, you should be using `DateTimeOffset` for this scenario, not `DateTime`.  Otherwise you will have incorrect results if there's a DST transition between the clock in/out times.  Alternatively you could do `clockOut.ToUniversalTime() - clockIn.ToUniversalTime()`, or you could just capture your times in UTC to begin with using `DateTime.UtcNow`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most importantly you need to read about variable scopes and Data Members.

Less importantly - following will work:

I just promoted your variable to be Class Data Member.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DateTime clockIn = DateTime.Min;  // Move Here

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void inButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           clockIn = DateTime.Now;
        }

        public void outButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime clockOut = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan timeWorked = clockOut - clockIn;

            string timeWorkedReport = $"Time worked = {timeWorked.Hours} hours, {timeWorked.Minutes} minutes";

            timeLabel.Text = timeWorkedReport;
        }
    }
```